# withRelated binding is undefined

Tags: bookshelf.js

I have two model:

```
    var Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: 'books',
        chapters: function(){
            var chapters = require('./chapter').Chapter;
            return this.hasMany(chapters, 'bookId');
        }
    });

    module.exports = {
        Book: Book
    };

var Chapter = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'chapters',
    hasTimestamps: ['dateCreated', 'dateUpdated'],

    //relationship
    book: function(){
        var book = require('./user').Book;
        return this.belongsTo(book, 'bookId');
    }
});

module.exports = {
    Chapter: Chapter
}
```

I do this in one of the controller:

```
new Book.Book()
                .fetch({withRelated:['chapters']})
                .then(function(books){
                    resolve(books);
                }).catch(function(err){
                    reject(err);
                });
```

The "chapters": [] because the debug log give me this, the bindings is undefined:

```
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings: [ 1 ],
  sql: 'select `books`.* from `books` limit ?' }
{ method: 'select',
  options: {},
  bindings: [ undefined ],
  sql: 'select `chapters`.* from `chapters` where `chapters`.`bookId` in (?)' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bookshelf assumes that you have a column called 'id' in each table which uniquely identifies each row. If you are using a primary key which is not called 'id' you need to specify what it is called to be able to use the model in a relation. This is done by the 'idAttribute' member e.g.

```
var ModelA = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: "ModelA",
  idAttribute: "modelA_id"
  ...
}
```

});

http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-idAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with `idAttribute: 'cardId'` specified.

Comment: what? I have this same problem, could you make it more general?